# Spring Boot: @Transactional rollbackFor checked Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, transactions

I am trying to achieve transactional rollback when i will get checked exception from                 "**invokeProcedureForLead**" method(code mentioned below). I have tried multliple ways and some reference still
it is not working for me .

For more understanding please find below code

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public LeadResponseDTO processDataInDB(LMCRAResponseData lmcraResponse,
            Boolean crnPresentFlag, Map<Integer, Integer> craProcData,
            Map<Integer, Integer> crnProcData,LeadResponseDTO leadResponseDTO,LMCRARequestData lmcraRequestData) throws CRAProcessDBException,SQLException, CRAProcessClientException {
        try{
        leadResponseDTO = extractDecision(lmcraResponse,crnPresentFlag);
        
        decisionEngineResponseDao.invokeProceduresForLead(craProcData, crnProcData, lmcraResponse);
        
        }catch(Exception e){
              
        log.error("error in invokeProcCalls", e);
        if (masterErrorCodes.getErrorDTO("6006") != null)
            logException(lmcraResponse, masterErrorCodes.getErrorDTO("6006"));
         leadResponseDTO=new LeadResponseDTO(); 
         getLeadResponseDTO(lmcraRequestData,leadResponseDTO,e.getMessage());
        
    
        
        }       
    
        return leadResponseDTO;
    }



public void invokeProceduresForLead(Map<Integer, Integer> craProcData,
            Map<Integer, Integer> crnProcData, LMCRAResponseData lmcraResponseData) throws   Exception  {
        int noCRNFlag = 0;
        String commonLogs = CommonUtil.printDECommonLogs(lmcraResponseData);
    
        if (lmcraResponseData.isBureauMatch() && crnProcData.isEmpty())
            noCRNFlag = 1;

        
        if (lmcraResponseData.isBureauMatch()
                && invokeProcLeads(craProcData, DBConstants.CALL_PROC_PROCESS_CRA_DATA_LEAD,
                        Integer.parseInt(lmcraResponseData.getCaseID())) != null) {
            log.info("invokeProcLeads for Cra block - 1 for runId {} " , commonLogs);
            throw new CRAProcessDBException("error in invokeProcCalls for CRA");
            
            
        }
        if (crnProcData != null
                && !crnProcData.isEmpty()
                && invokeProcLeads(crnProcData, DBConstants.CALL_PROC_PROCESS_CRN_DATA_LEAD,
                        Integer.parseInt(lmcraResponseData.getCaseID())) != null) {
            log.info("invokeProcLeads for crn  block - 2 for runId {} " , commonLogs);
            throw new CRAProcessDBException("error in invokeProcCalls for CRN");
            
        }
        if (((crnProcData == null || crnProcData.isEmpty()) || !lmcraResponseData.isBureauMatch())
                && invokeNoCrnForLeads(DBConstants.CALL_PROC_PROCESS_NO_CRN_DATA_LEAD,
                        Integer.parseInt(lmcraResponseData.getCaseID()), noCRNFlag) != null) {
            log.info("invokeNoCrnForLeads block - 3 for runId {} " , commonLogs);
            throw new CRAProcessDBException("error in invokeProcCalls for NOCRN");
            
            
        }
```

Comment: You don't expect there to be a rollback for a *caught* exception, do you?

Comment: Since no exception is thrown by `processDataInDB` method, why do you expect rollback?

Comment: There is no call for invokeProceduresForLead in the method processDataInDB

Comment: yes. there is invokeProceduresForLead  call mentioned in  processDataInDB  "decisionEngineResponseDao.invokeProceduresForLead" check this line in "processDataInDB  ".  For example consider there are three procedure out that if third procedure will fail and throw an exception then it should rollback previous two procedure's executions. This what I am expecting

Answer (score 0):

I think the code needs to change like this -

```
log.error("error in invokeProcCalls", e);
```

if (masterErrorCodes.getErrorDTO("6006") != null)

logException(lmcraResponse, masterErrorCodes.getErrorDTO("6006"));

leadResponseDTO=new LeadResponseDTO(); getLeadResponseDTO(lmcraRequestData,leadResponseDTO,e.getMessage());

}

**throw e;**

Note that **throw e; ** line added..

The problem is you are throwing an exception from internal call, but then swallowing it in outer method. So the exception is never thrown from outer method, which results in no rollback happening.